# Would like to save the delta changes to s3 and retrieve them back with the delta

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to save the delta changes to s3 for a given file and just save the delta changes alone as a separate version and then when the latest version of the file needs to be accessed it should combine with the earlier file changes in return.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] and modify your question.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project. Can I suggest that you store negative/reverse deltas rather than positive/forward deltas - your primary use case will typically be 'get me the latest version' and consequently it does not make sense to start with v1 and apply N deltas every time. Instead always store the latest version fully, and store negative deltas for versions N-1 through 1. That aside, if you have specific coding questions then please ask them. As it stands, this question is too broad.

Comment: That sounds good, but is there any way I could store the negative deltas? can you please provide me with some references?

Comment: or any existing implementations?